# Sharing Keyboard image to WhatsApp Contact not shared directly

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-service

I have custom image keyboard app from which i am sharing image to any social media chatting application.

Now, As WhatsApp not supporting Commit content API to share image directly, I am using Intent to share image to WhatsApp.

Code is as below :

```
private void shareViaIntent(Context mContext, int iconPosition) {
    try {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType(getResources().getString(R.string.strIntentType));
        Uri uri = null;
        if (mStrPackageName.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.strWhatsAppPackage))) {
            //inorder to send images with white background to WhatsApp.
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.strFileProviderPackage), mArray_wapp_Icons[iconPosition]);
        } else {
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.strFileProviderPackage), mArray_Icons[iconPosition]);
        }
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareIntent.setPackage(mStrPackageName);
        startActivity(shareIntent);
    } catch (RuntimeException runTimeException) {
        runTimeException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, The **issue** is that When I am in open chat window for specific person. Means In WhatsApp app, If i am chatting with person named "xyz", then image is not sending directly to person named "xyz". It opens "SEND TO" window in WhatsApp, where i can select multiple contact to share image.
.
But, I just have to share selected image to that particualr "xyz" person.
So, Is there any changes needed in Intent as I have coded ?
Please, Guide.

Comment: I found some solutions using person's contact number, feedbacks from other developers are not consistent though. Can you get "xyz" contact number by just opening your keyboard on his chat window? If so, we could give it a try.

Comment: I know this is old, but did you find the solution?